# $Y$ can only take on $\{−1, 0, 1\}$. The expected value of $Y$ is $0$ and its variance is $1/2$. Find the probability distribution of $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

How would one approach this question?
A random variable Y can only take values in $\{−1, 0, 1\}$. The expected value of $Y$ is $0$ and its variance is $1/2$. Find the probability distribution of $Y$.

I'm having trouble understanding what the probability distribution would be without having the probabilities of each number occurring before hand. I've been trying to look for a way that incorporates both $E[X]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X]$ to calculate it, but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 4):

If $E[Y]=0$ what does that reveal about the probability that $Y=1$ and the probability that $Y=-1$. These two values should be equal, although we do not quite yet know what the probability necessarily is.

So, let the probability $Y=1$ be $p$. $E[Y]=1\cdot p +(-1)\cdot p +0\cdot (1-2p)=0$

What about the variance? Now, $Var(Y)=1\cdot p+1\cdot p+0\cdot(1-2p)=1/2$

Thus, $2p=1/2 \Rightarrow p=1/4$

Try going on from here.

Answer (score 2):

They want you to calculate the three unknowns.

You could try to find three equations.

They tell you that $E[Y] = 0$. Hence
$$E[Y] = \sum_{k=-1}^1 k\cdot p_k= -1\cdot p_{-1}+0\cdot p_0+1\cdot p_1 = 0.\tag 1$$

They tell you that $\text{Var}(Y) = 1/2$, and hence
$$\text{Var}(Y) = E[X^2]-\{E[Y]\}^2 = (-1)^2p_{-1}+0^2p_0+1^2p_1-(0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}.\tag 2$$

The final piece of information you have is that it must be that case that
$$p_{-1}+p_0+p_1 = 1.\tag 3$$

Hence, you have three equations and three unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $p(-1)+p(0)+p(1)=1 $ along with $E(X)=-p(-1)+p(1)=0$ and also $V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 = p(1)+p(1) = \frac{1}{2}$